# Fill value with column name if column's values are not NaNs in Excel

Tags: excel

Let's say we have the following excel table:

[image]

Now I need to create a new column `type`, if `cw`'s values are not `NaN`s, then fill `type` with `cw`, then check if `kf`'s values are not `NaN`s, then fill `type` with `kf`.

If both `cw` and `kf` have values then fill `cw` only.

How can I do that with Excel formula? Thanks.

The expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER([@CW]),"cw",IF(ISNUMBER([@KF]),"kf",""))
```

or

```
=IF(ISBLANK([@CW]),IF(ISBLANK([@KF]),"","kf"),"cw")
```

where `[@CW]` and `[@KF]` are references to cells in the CW and KF columns, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I use your second formula since my real data are not number but strings. One more question, if we have the third column `savills`, how could I modify your furmula?

Comment: @ahbon The formulas in my answer are both nested `IF` statements --- two `IF`s for the two columns. To handle a third column you would replace the "empty" result (the repeated double-quotes) by another `IF`, maybe something like `IF(ISBLANK([@SV]),"","sv")`